# Check whether a file is in particular directory or not with JFileChooser

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I have make a program where I have to save file in `.db format` using `JFileChooser`. But the problem is when I create a file with the same name it shows the same message for creating same file or creating a new file. It show the same result `False` in every case. This is my code for more Clear understanding !

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            int answer=JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Do You Want To Create New Company ?","Confirm Dialog",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
            switch(answer)
            {
            case JOptionPane.YES_OPTION:
                File file=new File("Database");
                file.mkdirs();
                JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser(file);
                fc.setDialogTitle("Enter Inventory Plus File Name");
                fc.setMultiSelectionEnabled(false);
                fc.removeChoosableFileFilter(fc.getAcceptAllFileFilter());
                FileTypeFilter filefilter=new FileTypeFilter(".db","database");
                fc.setFileFilter(filefilter);
                int result = fc.showSaveDialog(null);
                if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    File fileName=fc.getSelectedFile();
                    String filename=fileName.getName();
                    String filepath=fileName.getParent();
                    if(fileName.exists())
                    {
                        String message="File "+filename+".db"+" already exist in\n"+filepath+"\nDo you want to Overwrite?\n";
                        int reply=JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, message,"Warning",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                        if(reply==JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
                        {
                            try {
                                fileName.delete();
                                BufferedWriter writer=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName+".db"));
                                writer.close();
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File "+filename+".db"+" is Overwritten Successfully in\n"+filepath);
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            try {
                                BufferedWriter writer=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName+".db"));
                                writer.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                    }
                }
            case JOptionPane.NO_OPTION:
            }
        }

public class FileTypeFilter extends FileFilter{

        private final String Extension;
        private final String Description;
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File file) {
            if(file.isDirectory()) {
            return true;
            }
            return file.getName().endsWith(Extension);
        }

        public FileTypeFilter(String extension, String description) {
            super();
            Extension = extension;
            Description = description;
        }

        @Override
        public String getDescription() {
            return Description + String.format("(*%s)", Extension);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Cannot understand your question. Please provide a [mcve] and better describe where is your problem.

Comment: When I create file with same filename it has to be show message that file is already exists and when I create a new file with different file name it show the same message that file is already exists. That is my problem.

Comment: In both the cases it shows the same message that file exist either we create a new file with different filename or same file with same same.

Comment: .. where is the MCVE that @SergiyMedvynskyy suggested you post as an [edit]?

Answer (score 0):

The Solution is I have to check all files in that directory and match the filename with its extention if any file have the same name which is already in that directory it show message that the file is already exists otherwise it create a new file with that name if file have different name which is not in that directory.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                int answer=JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Do You Want To Create New Company ?","Confirm Dialog",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                switch(answer)
                {
                case JOptionPane.YES_OPTION:
                    File file=new File("Database");
                    file.mkdirs();
                    JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser(file);
                    fc.setDialogTitle("Enter Inventory Plus File Name");
                    fc.setMultiSelectionEnabled(false);
                    fc.removeChoosableFileFilter(fc.getAcceptAllFileFilter());
                    FileTypeFilter filefilter=new FileTypeFilter(".db","database");
                    fc.setFileFilter(filefilter);
                    int result = fc.showSaveDialog(null);
                    if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                        File[] dircontent=file.listFiles();
                        File fileName=fc.getSelectedFile();//Database\Second
                        String filename=fileName.getName();//second,first
                        String filepath=fileName.getParent();//database
                        for(int i=0;i<dircontent.length;i++)
                        {
                            if(dircontent[i].getName().equals(filename+".db"))
                                    {
                                String message="File "+filename+".db"+" already exist in\n"+filepath+"\nDo you want to Overwrite?\n";
                                int reply=JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, message,"Warning",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                                if(reply==JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
                                {
                                    try {
                                        fileName.delete();
                                        BufferedWriter writer=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName+".db"));
                                        writer.close();
                                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File "+filename+".db"+" is Overwritten Successfully in\n"+filepath);
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                                    }
                            else
                            {
                                    try {
                                        BufferedWriter writer=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName+".db"));
                                        writer.close();
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                case JOptionPane.NO_OPTION:
                }
            }


            public class FileTypeFilter extends FileFilter{

        private final String Extension;
        private final String Description;
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File file) {
            if(file.isDirectory()) {
            return true;
            }
            return file.getName().endsWith(Extension);
        }

        public FileTypeFilter(String extension, String description) {
            super();
            Extension = extension;
            Description = description;
        }

        @Override
        public String getDescription() {
            return Description + String.format("(*%s)", Extension);
        }

    }
```